# Overriding the subscript operator in String class

Tags: c++

I am working on building a string class in C++.  Currently I am trying to override the subscript operator so users can get and modify individual characters.

```
#ifndef STRING_HPP
#define STRING_HPP

#include "test.hpp"
#include <cstring>
#include <iosfwd>


struct String
{
  // Defines the npos value.
  static constexpr std::size_t npos = -1;
  int len;
  char *str;
  String()
  :len(0), str(0){}

  String(char const * S)
  :len(strlen(S)), str(new char[len + 1]){
    assert(S != 0);
    strcpy(str, S);
  }

  ~String(){
    delete[]str;
  }

  String (char *S, std::size_t const n)
  :len(n), str(new char[len + 1]){
    assert(S != 0);
    assert(strlen(S) >= n);
    strncpy(str, S, n);
    str += '\0';
  }


  String operator +=(String const &S){
    int n = len + S.len;
    char * p = new char[n+1];
    strcpy(p + len, S.str);
    len = n;
    str = p;
    return *this;
  }

  char* data() const {
    return this->str;
  }

  bool empty() const {
    return (this->len == 0);
  }

  size_t size()const {
    size_t temp = len;
    return temp;
  }

  //assignment operator
  String operator =(String const &s){
    String temp(s);
    swap(temp);
    return *this;
  }

  void swap(String &s){
    std::swap(len, s.len);
    std::swap(str, s.str);
  }

  size_t find(const char c){
    char * p = strchr(this->str, c);
    if(p){
      return (str - p);
    }else{
       return npos;
    }
  }

  char &operator[](const size_t pos){
    assert(pos >= 0);
    assert(pos < this->size());
    return str[pos];
 //return output;
  }

  String substr(int index, int dist){
    String output((this->str + index) ,dist);
    return output;
  }
};


// Output
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, String const&);
//String operator +=(String const &);
bool operator <(String const &, String const &);
bool operator >(String const &, String const &);
bool operator <=(String const &, String const &);
bool operator >=(String const &, String const &);
bool operator ==(String const &, String const &);

#endif
```

The portion of main that calls the subscript function is:

```
String s1 = "String";
s1[0] = 'a';
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: passing 'const String' as 'this' argument of 'char& String::operator[](size_t)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Thanks!

**Edit**

Updated error message to be correct

Comment: Side Note: `assert(pos >= 0);` is always good for a pos of type size_t

Comment: Compiles for me (outside of some missing `#include`s). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `String operator +=` is wrong

Comment: Also: You violate the rule of 3 (5)

Comment: `String operator +=` has a memory leak.  Maybe you should be unit testing all of your functions first.  `+=` was not clearly unit tested.

Comment: Cannot duplicate: http://ideone.com/r6sNxf

Comment: I took a close look and I discovered that the code I posted didn't reflect what I was running (missing '&'), I've updated with the correct error message.  Also thanks for the tip about the memory leak in operator +=.

Comment: You need to write two overloads for `operator []` -- a const version and a non-const version.

Answer (score -1):

turns out the answer is just to add a 'const' at the end of the function:

```
  char &operator[](const size_t pos)const{
    assert(pos >= 0);
    assert(pos < this->size());
    return str[pos];
 //return output;
  }
```

Comment: No, you do *not* want to do that. That's making a supposedly `const` string actually mutable. Rather, the version with `const` applied to `this` should be an overload that returns `char const &`.

Comment: That isn't the answer.  You're supposed to write two overloads of `operator []` -- a `const` version and a non-const version.  Do a search on SO and other places explaining how to properly overload the subscript operator.